# Can pdf document generated with maatwebsite/excel contain many columns/ Horizontall scrolling?

Tags: pdf-generation, maatwebsite-excel

in Laravel 8 with    "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1" I try to write to pdf file document with many columns
and I try to set Orientation = LANDSCAPE with code :

```
class HostelsByIdExport implements FromCollection, WithEvents, WithHeadings, WithPreCalculateFormulas, WithColumnFormatting, ShouldAutoSize, WithColumnWidths, WithStyles
{
    public function __construct(array $hostelsList)
    {
    ...
    }

    public function collection()
    {
       ...
    }

    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            // Handle by a closure.
            BeforeExport::class  => function (BeforeExport $event) {
               ...
            },


            // Array callable, refering to a static method.
            BeforeWriting::class => [self::class, 'beforeWriting'],

            AfterSheet::class => function (AfterSheet $event) {
                $event->sheet  ->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);


            }, // AfterSheet::class => function (AfterSheet $event) {

        ];
    }
```

as I read in 3.1 documentations at https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/extending.html

and it works ok, but even landscape genarated page can not contain all columns and I see tyhat many columns are cut off.
Are there some decisions here? Maybe something like Horizontall scrolling ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could extend one of the existing writers. But realistically, you'd probably be better off going directly to a well-documented PDF library for creating a customized PDF export.

Comment: Could you please point to such well-documented PDF library/docs link ?